# RuntimeError (Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (no such file to load -- java))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, java, netbeans6.8

My Rails server worked well through normal development scripting and I planned to use Netbeans for Rails. When I started my existing project with Netbeans and restarted my Webrick server, It shows error

**RuntimeError (Please install the jdbcmysql adapter: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` (no such file to load -- java))**

I feel this error is related with JRuby, But I never using JRuby and I am using Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.0 and I dont want to use JRuby and Glassfish. I tried to remove default JRuby and Ruby1.9.2 as default, but i cant. I feel there may be a cause of linking error w.r.t JRuby. Kindly help me to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Got the same error. 
Look in your **config/database.yml** - netbeans changes the adapter automatically. Just write 'sqlite3' as adapter or whatever fits for you instead of 'jdbcmysql'.

Hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue, In Netbeans,,, i set Ruby 1.9.2 as default by

**Project -> Right Click "My project" -> Set Configuration ->Customize -> Changed Ruby Platform as "Ruby 1.9.2" from "JRuby".**

Now it works without any error. This may help for some other reader.

-- 
With Thanks,
Palani Kannan. K,

Comment: It didn't work for me yet. And I don't think that netbeans configuration may fix the error. Can you guide me more on that issue?

Comment: @Nimesh: For my case, it was ruby executable link problem... I dont know about your problem. May be if you post your problem exactly, the known people will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't install the necesary gem, that's all. You need to do this: `gem install activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter` to install necesary aditional gems, and then you have to edit your `database.yml` with the proper gem, for example:

```
development:
  adapter: jdbcmysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: db_development
  pool: 5
  username: username
  password: passwrd
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your database.yml file you will find that tha adapter have been changed from your previous configured database to jdbcmysql.
 you can delete it and write it back!

For example:

```
 development:
    adapter: jdbcmysql
```

and if you were using mysql

```
 development:
    adapter: mysql2
```

And it will works!